# How to make setTimeout work even after the Discord Bot restarts?

Tags: discord.js

i have made a **setTimeout** function to delete data from a database of a discord bot as it's a feature named "Monthly Subscription" where you subscribe for a bot feature and it auto expires (*deleting their data from db*) after 1 month, but this doesn't seems to be working as the bot can go some restarts at random times and the **setTimeout** gets deleted or removed so that the function inside that didn't worked. so any fix for this?

Comment: Consider using the Cron package

Comment: Do you want to use `setTimeout` to execute some function a month later? The max timeout is something like 24-25 days as if `delay` is larger than 2_147_483_647ms, the delay will be set to 1. Check out cron, as @Elitezen mentioned.